# How to resolve performance issues when resizing window with ScrollViewer enabled

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, scrollviewer

I have a View in which my UserControl with lots of content is wrapped with ScrollViewer. When I resize window with mouse I have very pure performance. When I remove ScrollViewer wrapped around UserControl performance issue disappears. How can I use ScrollViewer without performance drops on resizing window with mouse?

Comment: On drag start you can set user control's width and height to actual width and height. On drag stop you can make control's width and height automatic again. But usually this problem arises when you wrap ScrollViewer around a control that already has implicit ScrollViewer, for example ListBox or DataGrid

Comment: Yes, I have DataGrid and ListView inside my UserControl. I disabled horizontal and vertical scroll-bars for them and still have performance issues...

Comment: Then do not wrap UserControl's content in ScrollViewer. And usually it's not a good idea to disable ScrollBars for these controls. Better put contens of your custom control in Grid or DockPanel